# HCS12 postfix calculator with assembly language

Tags: assembly, stack, branch

I am having trouble figuring out how to get my code to only access certain functions based on branch statements. Rather than skipping the function it does not equal it just goes through the first function and then loops forever only accessing the first function when I want it to stop after a certain length and only access the functions it needs to access. I wrote the C++ code to help me figure out what I'm missing and I got that to work but I have no idea how to convert that into assembly language. It would be great if someone could please give me some advice or give me more clarification on how to use each branch as well as which branches would work well in this situation. Thanks in advance! :D

```
       XDEF      Entry       ; export 'Entry' symbol
       ABSENTRY  Entry       ; for absolute assembly: mark this as application entry point

       ROM:          EQU     $0400
       DATA:        EQU     $1000
       PROG:     EQU     $2000

     ORG     DATA         
      ORG     PROG
   EQUATION      FCB $05, $01, $02, $2B, $04, $2A, $2B, $03, $2D     ;(512+4*+3-)
   INDEX         FCB $00
   TEMP          FCB $00
   ; Insert your code following the label "Entry"          
    Entry:                          ; KEEP THIS LABEL!!

      LDS     #PROG
      LDX    #EQUATION
      LDAB   INDEX

   LOOP:
LDAA  B,X
TSTA

CMPA #$2F
BEQ    DIVIDE
DIVIDE:
STAB   TEMP
PULX
PULD
IDIVS
PSHD
PULA
LDAB  TEMP
BRA     RET

CMPA #$2D
BEQ     SUBTRACT
SUBTRACT:
STAB     TEMP
PULB
PULA
SBA
PSHA
LDAB     TEMP
BRA     RET

CMPA #$2B
BEQ     ADD
ADD:
STAB     TEMP
PULA
PULB
ABA
PSHA
LDAB     TEMP
BRA     RET

CMPA #$2A
BEQ      MULTIPLY
MULTIPLY:
STAB     TEMP  
PULA
PULB
MUL
PSHA
LDAB     TEMP
BRA     RET    

PSHA
RET:
INCB
CMPB $09     
BHI     LOOP





      ; Branch to end of program
      BSR     FINISH           
       FINISH: END
```

Using Freescale CodeWarrior IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem looks like a common switch/case thing as in C, where you write

```
switch(char) {
    case '*' : <do multiply> break;
    case '/' : <do divide> break;
    case '+' ...
```

which jumps over each code block if the condition is NOT fulfilled. The normal approach on this in assembly is similar, and looks like what you tried. BUT: your jump conditions are wrong

```
   cmp <value>
   beq label
label:
```

this **always** jumps to (or automatically moves into) label.

you have inverted the branch condition:

```
    CMPA #$2F
    BNE    NO_DIVIDE    ; it'S NOT a divide, so skip the code for divide
DIVIDE:
    STAB   TEMP
    PULX
    PULD
    IDIVS
    PSHD
    PULA              ; what is this for??
    LDAB  TEMP
    BRA     RET
NO_DIVIDE:
```

another option was, to have all operations in a set of subfunctions, and jump to them from a comparation, like you tried to (this is often not possible for the limited range of branches):

```
CMPA #$2f
BEQ DIVIDE
CMPA #$2D
BEQ SUBTRACT
CMPA #$2B
BEQ ADD
CMPA #$2A
BEQ MULTIPLY
...

DIVIDE:
    <do the divide stuff>
    BRA RET
MULTIPLY:
    <do the multiply stuff>
    BRA RET
etc
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It runs how its supposed to now :D